# Rails environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

I need to define a set of variables for my development environment and also my production environment. How should I do this on Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gem [rails_config](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) do a great job

Answer (score 1):

Also, this is another option [rails_settings](https://github.com/dapi/rails_settings) , is really easy and you can implement it with just look the code